# Numpy: how to select the max of an array into another arrays

Tags: python, numpy

My data looks like this:

```
array = np.array([1,2],[3,4],[4,5])
```

How to find the max of the first element [0] amongst all the arrays and take the second element of this specific array. In this case it will be: max of the first element of all the arrays = 4, second element of this specific array=5.

I know how to do it with a for loop, but as my data are really really large, does anyone have an idea on how do it simplier? Thanks!

Comment: `np.array([1,2],[3,4],[4,5])` is not valid syntax for `np.array`, please check and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54307161/edit).

Comment: can you specify what you want for example from this array = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[4,4],[4,5]])  ? Your question doesnt specify more possibilities, like more max values amongst first elements

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this in order to retrieve the "5":

```
    array[np.argmax(array[:,0],axis=0),1]
```

Comment: argmax gives you the location of the maximal value. so what i did is getting the maximal value in the first colomn of array. this would yield 2. then putting this in array[<argmax here>,1] would give the element at position 2 (row wise) and column 1 which in this case is 5

Comment: @LiorT Your algorithm doesnt work for more max values in first elements.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do if there are more elements with maximal first element than 1, for example for input: `[[1,3],[1,4]]` output should be `3` or `4`?
Anyway you can do it without `numpy` following way

```
data = [[1,2],[3,4],[4,5]]
m = max(data,key=lambda x:x[0])[1]
print(m) #prints 5
```

will get first maximum value, if you replace middle line with
    m = max(data)[1]
it would get maximal second value amongst maximum first values

Answer (score -1):

1) find index of MAX VALUE of first elements

```
array = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[4,5]])
```

search for that value among first elements

```
index = np.where(array[:,0] == np.amax(array[:,0]))
```

2) find the second element

```
element = array[index][0][1]
```

Note that there can be more max values among first elements
so  array[index] finds all of such arrays and its up to you which one you want to examine